# How can I create a distance matrix containing the mean absolute scores between each row?

Tags: r, matrix, distance, vegan, distance-matrix

Given the matrix,

```
df <- read.table(text="
 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  1  2  3  2  1
  2  3  4  4  3
  3  4  4  6  2
  4  5  5  5  4
  2  3  3  3  6
  5  6  2  8  4", header=T)
```

I want to create a distance matrix containing the absolute mean difference between each row of each column. For example, the distance between `X1` and `X3` should be = 1.67 given that:

abs(1 - 3) + abs(2-4) + abs(3-4) + abs(4-5) + abs(2-3) + abs(5-2) = 10 / 6 = 1.67

**I have tried** using the `designdist()` function in the vegan package this way:

```
designdist(t(df), method = "abs(A-B)/6", terms = "minimum")
```

The resulting distance for columns 1 and 3 is 0.666. The problem with this function is that it sums all the values in each column and then subtracts them. But I need to sum the absolute differences between each row (individually, absolute) and then divide it by N.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a one-line solution. It takes advantage of `dist()`'s `method` argument to calculate the [L1 norm aka city block distance aka Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) between each pair of columns in your data.frame.

```
as.matrix(dist(df, "manhattan", diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)/nrow(df))
```

To make it reproducible:

```
df <- read.table(text="
 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
  1  2  3  2  1
  2  3  4  4  3
  3  4  4  6  2
  4  5  5  5  4
  2  3  3  3  6
  5  6  2  8  4", header=T)

dmat <- as.matrix(dist(df, "manhattan", diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)/nrow(df))
print(dmat, digits=3)
#      1     2     3    4     5    6
# 1 0.00 1.167 1.667 2.33 1.333 3.00
# 2 1.17 0.000 0.833 1.17 0.833 2.17
# 3 1.67 0.833 0.000 1.00 1.667 1.67
# 4 2.33 1.167 1.000 0.00 1.667 1.33
# 5 1.33 0.833 1.667 1.67 0.000 2.33
# 6 3.00 2.167 1.667 1.33 2.333 0.00
```